# Trying to swap positions in a list

Tags: python, python-3.7

Writing a simple code to print a random list, the swap the first position integer with the last position integer and re-print the list. Keep getting error saying not subscriptable. This is for a basic python class but we are on Thanksgiving break and can't talk to professor, due when we get back.

```
import random

def main():

    mylist=[]

    for i in range(15):
        mylist.append(random.randrange(0,25))

    print(mylist)



    def swap():
        a, b = mylist.index[0], mylist.index[14]
        mylist[b], mylist[a] = mylist[a], mylist[b]
        print(mylist)

    swap()

main()
```

Comment: `a` and `b` will be set to the first and last elements of the list, so trying to access `mylist[a]` and `mylist[b]` is wrong (`a` and `b` are not indices, they are the actual values). Try `mylist[0], mylist[14] = a, b` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You need to hold one of the values in a variable and then swap.

```
def swap():
    x = mylist[0]
    mylist[0] = mylist[14]
    mylist[14] = x

    print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are swapping with indexes equal to the values in the list (instead of indexes).

Try:

`mylist[0], mylist[-1] = mylist[-1], mylist[0]`

On another observation, I believe you have to pass mylist to `swap` as a parameter. (unless swap is defined in main).